# A search bar with Auto Complete, to search data in JavaScript Arrays/Objects (not Ajax)

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I want to implement a 'Search with Auto complete drop down' but I don't need ajax as all the data I need is already in JavaScript Arrays/Objects/Maps. Whats the most easiest way to implement this kind of search feature? It will be great if some one can post some simple example or point me to a tutorial.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry A very Basic Question. I found the answer on one search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to include jQuery UI, you could try something like [Better Autocomplete](https://github.com/betamos/Better-Autocomplete).

Comment: Excellent Suggestion! This one is on top of jQuery and is as the name goes Lot better! Thanks!

Comment: A Question here, why do you say "if i am not using jQuery UI" Cant i use the jQuery UI and Better Auto complete?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Of course you can use them both, but Better Autocomplete is smaller and depends only of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#events